# Having trouble with splitting strings in C

Tags: c

I'm having trouble with splitting strings and the proper use of the function strtok:

Here's my problem:

I'm reading from stdin, and i want to split the input the following way:

```
<command> <key> <data>
```

"PUT 122gyhbhb  having trouble with splitting strings and the proper use of the function streak:"

the first word(PUT) is the command, the second is the key and the other words until the end of input are the data.

Here's what i've done so far:

```
char *buffer = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 2048); 

fgets(buffer,2048, stdin);

char *options = strtok(buffer, " ");

char *key = strtok(NULL," ");
char *data = strtok(NULL, " ");
```

However this gets me the command, the key, but only the first word of the data. How can i change this, so it does what i want ? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the delimiter for the last call to `strtok`:

```
char *data = strtok(NULL, "\n");
```

Comment: OR you could loop it : `while( strtok(buffer, " ") != NULL) { // do what you want here}`